# Getting errors when compiling GLEW/SDL program

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I've got this code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
...
```

What went wrong?
It seems like glu.h belongs to a MinGW package. I'm using NetBeans with Cygwin.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the version of gcc that ships with MinGW does not understand your `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` directives. Those are non-standard Microsoft Visual C directives that tell the linker to use those libraries. You are going to need to add things like `-lglew32` and `-lSDL2` to your linker command line to make this portable. Additionally, CALLBACK probably is not defined... GLU ought to take care of this, but if it does not `#include <Windows.h>` (which implicitly includes **WinDef.h**) certainly will.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that your code snippet is what's actually compiled. The error messages mention GLU definitions. Those are found in the `GL/glu.h` include which is mentioned nowhere in your snippet and also isn't included in neither `glew.h` nor `SDL.h`.

Anyway, the error is most likely due to a lack of the definition of the Windows-specific `APIENTRY` macro (it's only expected in builds on/for the Windows OS). Either include `windows.h` or define the macro yourself.

I suggest using this before including anything OpenGL related.

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN32__) \
 || defined(__TOS_WIN__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
/* Compiling for Windows */
#ifndef __WINDOWS__
#define __WINDOWS__
#endif
#  include <windows.h>
#endif/* Predefined Windows macros */
```